# Firebase not showing data on load

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Firebase fetch doesn't initiate automatically. have to do some action to show the data.

My Slides page fetching some data. once I load on this page, it shows nothing, but once I refresh it, it show me data.

I don't know, why its happening. Any solution
TIA

**Services**

```
slides: Observable<Slides[]>;

this.slides = this.db
      .collection("Slides")
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(changes => {
          return changes.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Slides;
            data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data;
          });
        })
      );
```

**Component**

```
this.serv.getSlides().subscribe( res => {
      this.slides = res;
    });
```

**Framework**
Angular7 + AngularFire2

Comment: Where are u retrieving the data in your component?

Comment: component, but calling from services.